# Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in... (Localhost and PHP)

Tags: php, localhost

I have a problem with my code in localhost, i use wampserver.

I did not find the error and the solution.

The error is as follows:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\wamp\www\Test.php on line 74

```
$html = curl_exec($ch);
[...]
preg_match_all("(<title>(.*)<\/title>)siU", $html, $title);
$metas = get_meta_tags($url, 1);
/* Line 74 */ $title = $title[1][0];
$titulo = html_entity_decode("$title", ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$descripcion = isset($metas["description"])?$metas["description"] : '';
$keywords = isset($metas["keywords"])?$metas["keywords"] : '';
```

How they could solve??

Greetings and thanks!

Comment: You need to debug your code. What's in `$title`?

Comment: `if(isset($title[1][0])) ...` ?

Comment: print_r($title); after preg_match_all. Should give you some insight.

Comment: $title is the result of preg_match_all, I have the title of the webpage here.
PD: I'm testing the codes

Comment: The print show me: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Wiki - title ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( ) )

Answer (score 0):

`$title = $title[0][1][0];` is what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, but i have a new problem with your code: Notice: Undefined offset: 1

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not your question, but from what I can see I think this is the best solution:

```
<?php

//If yout allow_url_fopen is off, use CURL
$html = file_get_contents("http://example.com/"); 

//Parse html to object
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html); //To prevent some html errors

//Page title
$titles = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');
$title = $titles->item(0)->nodeValue;

//Meta tags
$metas = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');

//For each meta tag
for ($i = 0; $i < $metas->length; $i++) {

    $meta = $metas->item($i);

    //Check if description or keywords
    if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'description')
        $description = $meta->getAttribute('content');
    else if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'keywords')
        $keywords = $meta->getAttribute('content');
}

echo 'Title: '.$title;
echo 'Description: '.$description ;
echo 'Keywords: '.$keywords;

?>
```

Comment: I use:
`$html = file_get_contents($url); 
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
$titles = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');
$titulo = $titles->item(0)->nodeValue;` But i have a new problem: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in: `$titulo = $titles->item(0)->nodeValue;`

Comment: You need to test the return of variable `if($titles) { ... }`. Probably your HTML does returns any `title` tag, I recommend you to debug `$html` content.

Comment: Hello, I printed the variable $ html and this showing the full page and the title is correct.

Comment: And debugging the the `$titles` variable with `var_dump`, which returns you?

Comment: The $titulo returns: `string 'Documento sin tÃ­tulo' (length=21)` and below: `null`. And $titles shows: `object(DOMNodeList)[2]` and `object(DOMNodeList)[1048]`

Comment: You got a problem of logic in your code. The solution I posted earlier serves to solve the problem. You can see through this link that works perfectly as expected: http://codepad.org/x6varBvE